# How do I return ALL recently updated records for a particular customer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table:

```
somename   something       somedate
Tom        aaa             2013-07-30 15:16:07.710
Tom        bbb             2013-07-29 15:16:07.710
Matt       ccc             2013-07-28 15:16:07.710
Matt       ddd             2013-07-27 15:16:07.710
Matt       eee             2013-07-27 15:16:07.713
```

I want to return row 1 (most recent for customer Tom) and row 3 (most recent for customer Matt).

UPDATE: I added a 3rd column, 'something'

So the results should be:

someone 
tom 
matt

something 
aaa 
ccc

somedate 
2013-07-30 15:16:07.710 
2013-07-28 15:16:07.710

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: use the audit column in the table... say modified_date.
or if you keep an audit log table then would be handy.

or use audit feature in SQL Server (DW on DML)

Comment: Guys I added another column. I want to be able to retrive only rows 1  and 3.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  somename ,
        MAX(somadate)
FROM    attempts
GROUP BY somename
```

By grouping by `somename`, you will have 1 result for anyone called Tom, so this field would need to be **unique**.  So, maybe look for a unique field in the table, maybe `UserName` or `Email` etc. So, you would then end up with:

```
SELECT  somename ,
        MAX(somadate) ,
        UniqueField
FROM    attempts
GROUP BY somename ,
        UniqueField
```

Comment: What if my table had another field called 'something' and it contained all unique values but I wanted to return ALL 3 fields?

Answer (score 3):

here you go

```
select somename, max(somedate) from sometable group by somename
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using SQL Server, you can use `row_number()` to get the result:

```
select somename, somedate
from
(
  select somename, somedate,
    row_number() over(partition by somename
                      order by somedate desc) seq
  from yourtable
) d
where seq = 1;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8ec8/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable(
  SomeName VARCHAR(5),
  SomeDate DATE
 )

INSERT INTO SomeTable
VALUES ('Tom','2013-07-01')
  , ('Tom','2013-06-30')
  , ('Bob','2013-07-01')
  , ('Bob','2013-06-30')
  , ('Bob','2013-06-29')

SELECT DISTINCT SomeName, MAX(SomeDate)
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY SomeName
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71e5b/1)